# How can I return something early from a block?

Tags: ruby, loops, return, break

If I wanted to do something like this:

```
collection.each do |i|
   return nil if i == 3

   ..many lines of code here..
end
```

How would I get that effect? I know I could just wrap everything inside the block in a big if statement, but I'd like to avoid the nesting if possible.

Break would not work here, because I do *not* want to stop iteration of the remaining elements.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

`next` inside a block returns from the block. `break` inside a block returns from the function that yielded to the block. For `each` this means that `break` exits the loop and `next` jumps to the next iteration of the loop (thus the names). You can return values with `next value` and `break value`.

Comment: `break value` didn't work for me, while `next value` worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure your definition of next and break are correct. At the very least, they are confusing. break exits the innermost loop, next moves you to the next iteration.     
  source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: @WattsInABox `next` and `break` are in no way specific to looping constructs, so the article you linked is very misleading (since it heavily implies the opposite). And my descriptions are definitely correct when `next` and `break` are used inside blocks (note that `while` and `for` are rarely, if ever, used in Ruby so 99% of uses of `next` and `break` are within blocks).

Comment: I think you mean non-looping blocks. That's what's confusing about it. Also, I disagree with your 99% assertion, but that's a different argument.

Comment: I was looking for  a specific method on the Array class to do because I'm so used to having nice things like .detect, .map, .reduce. I knew I was missing something obvious when I couldn't find anything like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

stopped_at = collection.each do |i|
   break i if i == 3

   puts "Processed #{i}"
end

puts "Stopped at and did not process #{stopped_at}"
```

Answer (score 5):

In this instance, you can use break to terminate the loop early:

```
collection.each do |i|
  break if i == 3
  ...many lines
end
```

...of course, this is assuming that you're not actually looking to return a value, just break out of the block.

Comment: This would not just return from the block, it would return from each. So the loop would end, not continue with the next value. Not sure that that's what's intended.

Comment: You can use a value with `break` in Ruby — `break 5` will cause `each` to return 5.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to stop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is ancient, this still confuses me sometimes. I needed this for a more complicated use case with `[].select {|x| }`/`[].reject {|x| }`.

Common Use case

```
 [1,2,3,4,5].select{|x| x % 2 == 0 }
 => [2, 4]
```

But I needed to yield a specific value for each iteration and continue processing

With more complicated logic:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].select{|x| if x % 2 == 0; next true; end; false }
 => [2, 4] 
# you can also use `next(true)` if it's less confusing
```

Also, since it's relevant to the thread, using `break` here will emit the single value you pass in if the conditional hits:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].select{|x| if x % 2 == 0; break(true); end; false }
 => true 
[1,2,3,4,5].select{|x| if x % 2 == 0; break(false); end; false }
 => false 
[1,2,3,4,5].select{|x| if x % 2 == 0; break('foo'); end; false }
 => "foo"
```