# Passing a method that--when read--is the equivalent of return true

Tags: ruby

I have a method that accepts a method as an argument:

```
def acceptor_method(received_method)
  an_arry.each do |attr|
    received_method if some_condition
  end
end
```

This works well if all the `received_method` does is run through some code:

```
def some_method
  do_something
end
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
def acceptor_method(received_method)
  an_arry.each do |attr|
    do_something if some_condition
  end
end
```

But what if I want the `received_method` to break the loop and return a value, as with:

```
def acceptor_method(received_method)
  an_arry.each do |attr|
    return true if some_condition
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
def some_method
  return true
end
```

As it only returns true for `some method`, not for `acceptor_method`--which continues to play through the loop.

So is there a way to send a method that when run is the equivalent of `return true`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm interpreting your scenario properly, but just in case, watch out for terminology. You aren't ever passing the actual method (like you would a function in JavaScript). If you were to do `acceptor_method(some_method)`, the `some_method` method would be immediately called and resolved, and its return value would be sent as a parameter to `acceptor_method`. You could, however, pass a symbol to `acceptor_method` and call `send(:your_method_name_symbol)` to dynamically invoke the method. Have I misunderstood your scenario?

Comment: Thanks, Teeg. That clarifies a lot about how something like this would work. Unfortunately, I'm still struggling with the underlying problem, which is that I can't get `send(:method_symbol) if some_condition` to be the equivalent of `return true if some_condition`. The `return` within the received method remains caught within its own scope, so it does not return out of the acceptor method.

Comment: Two questions: Hypothetically, where would `some_condition` come from? Also, when you say you want it to be the equivalent of `return true...`, do you mean that you basically want to call your "received_method" conditionally (depending on `some_condition`), and have it return a boolean, essentially?

Comment: `some_condition` is defined within the `each` loop. (FYI, it's `changed_attributes.include? attr.key`) My goal is for the `received_method` to break out of the `each` loop and return `true` on behalf of `acceptor_method`--which I believe is what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def acceptor_method
  [1, 2, 3, 4].each do |attr|
    ret = yield attr
    puts attr
  end
end

test = acceptor_method do |attr|
  break 'test' if attr == 3
end

puts test
```

outputs:

```
1
2
test
```

Comment: It took some time for me to read up on blocks, but now that I get it, this solution works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using blocks rather than methods. See [How can I return something early from a block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518075/how-can-i-return-something-early-from-a-block)

Basically if you have a block with `break value` and `yield` to it, the function will return `value`. Unfortunately I don't see a way to do this using methods, since Ruby really doesn't like having `break` outside of a block or loop.