# Unexpected return error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to learning Ruby and am having a little trouble with nested structures.

What I'm trying to do is return :last name ("Doe") if the value of :first is "John":

```
people = {
  :family => [
    {:first => "John", :last => "Doe"},
    {:first => "Jane", :last => "Smith"}
  ]
}

people[:family].each {|index| return index[:last] if index[:first] == "John"}
```

However, the console is giving me this error:

```
test.rb:8:in `block in <main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
from test.rb:8:in `each'
from test.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

When I test this in the console and replace 'return' with 'puts', it gives me back "Doe" but for some reason the 'return' seems to be causing the 'unexpected return (LocalJumpError)'. How can I successfully return this value without running into this error?

Thanks - any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're returning inside the `.each`, which isn't the same as returning from a method (hence, unexpected). You want [`.select{}`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `return` within an `each` loop. You could use `map` or `collect` to return an array of last names like so:

```
people[:family].collect {|index| index[:last] if index[:first] == "John"}
=> ["Doe", nil]
```

You could also push your matches to an output variables like so:

```
output = []
people[:family].each {|index| output << index[:last] if index[:first] == "John"}
=> ["Doe"]
```

Using `break` as was suggested, will return a string of the first match, but if you have more than one match, it will not work for you. See example below:

```
people = {
  :family => [
    {:first => "John", :last => "Doe"},
    {:first => "Jane", :last => "Smith"},
    {:first => "John", :last => "Galt"}
  ]
}
people[:family].each {|index| break index[:last] if index[:first] == "John"}
=> "Doe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` with value

```
people = {
  :family => [
    {:first => "John", :last => "Doe"},
    {:first => "Jane", :last => "Smith"}
  ]
}

people[:family].each {|index| break index[:last] if index[:first] == "John"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` needs to be used inside a method:

```
def foo
  # your code
end

foo # => "Doe"
```

Comment: This isn't going to solve the problem. Returning inside the `.each` isn't allowed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518075/how-can-i-return-something-early-from-a-block

Comment: Maybe you should try it.

Comment: "Not allowed" isn't the right term, but there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts people[:family].find({}) {|index| index[:first] == "John"}[:last]
```