# How to use low-level Rails caching in a class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone explain to me why this attempt at caching not work?

```rb
# in an ActiveRecord model....
def self.label(da_code)
  Rails.cache.fetch [:option, :label, da_code, I18n.locale], expires_in: 3.hours do
    option = Option.i18n.find_by(code: da_code)
    return option.title if option

    da_code
  end
end
```

I'm using mobility here for translation. The way I see it, this shouldn't hit the database at all, once it's been loaded. But it always does hit the db, as if the cache isn't being used at all. I have enabled caching in development mode, and I've verified it works in other places in my app.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you verify it with `def self.label(code); Rails.cache.fetch([:option, code]) { puts "CACHE miss" }; end` and then in the console do : `Model.label(:whatever) #=> CACHE miss` `Model.label(:wathever)` second time should not be a "CACHE miss"

Comment: @Alex - it shows "cache miss" every time I run the method. it's not caching.

Comment: "I have enabled caching in development mode" - are you sure? what does this show in the console  `Rails.application.config.cache_store`?

Comment: @dbugger - I think that's what Rails does anyway under the hood? But I tried it, and same results.

Comment: @Alex - I'm as sure as I can be, I suppose. Runnig that command in the console returns `:memory_store`.

Comment: I think the return may be interfering with the cache getting set -- replace `return option.title if option` with `option&.title`

Comment: @debugger - using your suggestion does make the cache work. But without the return statement, I can't return the value of `da_code`.

Comment: return it outside of the cache block. also -you are passing in da_code, why do you need to return it?

Comment: @debugger - the return value of this method goes into an HTML form label, so I want it to return something if it doesn't find an Option with that code. I'll be happy to accept your answer if you want to write it up below.

Comment: in this situation you can also use `next` (or `break`) instead of a `return`.

Comment: @Alex - can you provide a quick example? I've not used next or break in that way.

Comment: literally replace `return` with `next`: `next option.title if option` https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518171/207090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the return is interfering with the cache getting set.

try...

```
    def self.label(da_code)
      title = nil
      Rails.cache.fetch [:option, :label, da_code, I18n.locale], expires_in: 3.hours do
        option = Option.i18n.find_by(code: da_code)
        title = option&.title
      end
      title.present? ? title : da_code
    end
```